# How to loop a list of items infinitely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop the set of li items like a loop vertically upward without a end with a 5000ms delay between each loop. I want to move up list items smoothly as well.

My code triggers the loop every 5000ms in the beginning but it does not move items upward smoothly. And after few iterations of loop it runs very faster.

Here is the jquery code I am trying.

```
function tick(){
    $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({top:"-225px"},"slow");
    $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");

    setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
}

//Call on page load
$(tick);
```

I cannot figure out what is the reason to the issue. Please help me to get through this.

Thanks.

EDIT : I've made a fiddle but haven't thought to include it into my question... http://jsfiddle.net/654DX/2/.

Comment: Probably not the issue but in your case, Use `setTimeout`. You end up firing so many interval callbacks.

Comment: Or take `setInterval` out of the function. Call it once at page load time.

Comment: Try `function tick() {
    $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({
        top: "-225px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");

}
//Call on page load
$(tick);
setInterval(tick, 5000);`

Comment: @PSL: Very much the issue :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the support. With this code which I received from two answers below now the loop triggers every 5secs but items does not animate upward slowly. Can you also point me the issue for that?.


function tick(){

    setInterval(function(){  
        $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({top:"-225px"},"slow");
        $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");
    }, 5000);
}

//Call on page load
$(tick);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest mistake I've noticed in your script is the recursive use of `setInterval`. Indeed, `setInterval` calls the passed function repeatedly (unlike `setTimeout`), so, every 5 seconds, the number of calls increases exponentially (1, 2, 4...). In other words, every 5 seconds `setInterval` calls `setInterval`, which does the same, and so on...

Then, I guess you wanted to subtract 225 pixels from the original position, rather than going to this position. In case I'm right, replace `-225px` with `-=225px`.

Lastly, I guess you would have prefered to wait until all animations are done before moving the first item to the end of the list (remember that `animate` applies to each item individually).

All fixes together :

```
$(function tick() {
    var h = $('li:first').outerHeight(true);
    var anim = $('li').animate({ top: '-=' + h + 'px' }, 'slow');
    $.when(anim).done(function () {
        $('li:first').appendTo('ul');
        $('li').css('top', 'auto');
        setTimeout(tick, 5000);
    });
});
```

I've made something similar : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/GJvLw/.

Answer (score 3):

```
function tick(){

    setInterval(function(){  
        $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({top:"-225px"},"slow");
        $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");
    }, 5000);
}

//Call on page load
$(tick);
```

the way you have it coded up in the question is going to spawn lots and lots of tick() that is why you notice the speed up. Coding it this way allows for only a single tick() and thus will produce the effect once every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks I understand your point and it does not speedup now. But items does not move up slowly. What may be the cause for that?

Comment: when you say they don't move up slowly do you mean the "slow" argument to .animate is not as slow as you like? if that is the case try adding a custom time interval instead of "slow". Try 750

Comment: no no it just only switch from one to one even I give a custom value nothing changes.

Comment: @Learner Include the fiddle into your question!

Answer (score 1):

everytime execute tick also execute setInterval again!

u can try like that:

```
function tick() {
    $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({top:"-225px"},"slow");
    $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");
}

$(function(){
    setInterval(tick, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I understand your point and it does not speedup the loop now. But items does not move up slowly. What may be the cause for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need your element goes to -225px position or moves every tick on 225px upper? If the second then you need `-=225px`, and the code will be:

```
function tick() {
     var $elems = $('#itemflowslider ul li');

     if ($elems.position().top < 225) {
         $elems.animate({top: 0 }, "slow");
         return;
     }

     $elems.animate({top: "-=225px"},"slow"); // slow means = 600 ms!
     $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");

     setTimeout(tick, 5000); // start tick again
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    tick(); // start loop
});
```

`Slow` = 600 ms, so 4400ms (5000 - 600) nothing will move and will go when it time elasped.

**EDIT**:

According to the comments I updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/654DX/11/)

```
function tick() {

    var $ul = $('#itemflowslider ul');
    var $li1 = $ul.find("li").first();

    $ul.append($li1.clone());
    $li1.css({
        height: '1em',
        visibility: 'hidden'
    })
    .animate({height: 0}, 'slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    setTimeout(tick, 5000); // start tick again
}

$(tick);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support I want to move -=225px on every tick but when I use -=225px it works but after few runs list goes out from the visible area. Because it increment the location by -225px on every tick.

How can I use -=225px and keep the list in the visible area?.

Comment: @Learner You need to define some limit, where it should stop? When reaches the top? See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. But this is not exactly what I need. Here is the fiddle run for your code. http://jsfiddle.net/654DX/9/

I want to move list items 225px upward and append the first list item to last. Finally UL stays in a one place and LIs remove from top and append to bottom when they reach the invisible area.

Comment: @Learner Oh, I guess I understand finally, see my updated answer and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/654DX/11/. I hope it is what we were searching for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support given to solve my issue. Actually in your fiddle it comes down when switch to the next. Anyway your help was a great support for me to explain my requirement to others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

u can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({top:"-225px"},"slow");
      $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");

   },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to calculate the loop time to make sure your animation have been finished. I mean something like this:

```
$(function(){
   tick();
});

function tick(){ 
   $('#itemflowslider ul li').animate({top:"-225px"}, 'slow', function(){
       $("#itemflowslider ul li:first").appendTo("#itemflowslider ul");
       setInterval(tick, 5000);
   });
}
```